# Rust E0463 building Dioxus Fullstack but wasm32-unknown-unknown Target is Installed

Tags: rust, webassembly, toolchain, dioxus

Running `dx build --features web --release` or `cargo build --target wasm32-unknown-unknown` returns the following error:

```
[INFO]  Running build command...
error: Broken pipe (os error 32)
Error:  Building project failed: error[E0463]: can't find crate for `std`
  |
  = note: the `wasm32-unknown-unknown` target may not be installed
  = help: consider downloading the target with `rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown`
```

However, when I run `rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown`, it prints

```
info: component 'rust-std' for target 'wasm32-unknown-unknown' is up to date
```

The target appears to be installed when I run `rustup show`:

```
Default host: aarch64-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/myhomedir/.rustup

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

aarch64-apple-darwin
wasm32-unknown-unknown

active toolchain
----------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
rustc 1.76.0 (07dca489a 2024-02-04)
```

I don't understand why the std lib isn't compiled for this target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Rust was installed via both `homebrew` and `rustup`. Removing the homebrew installation fixed this. Credit to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74549777/22985331